# Will not let me pass an array of arrays of string to a class property?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class called `FilesTableViewController` with this property

```
  var files:[[String]]?
```

On `prepareforsegue` of another class I have this:

```
  let textFiles:[String]? = FileManager.default.getSortedFilesAtDocumentDirectoryWith(fileExtension: "txt", withFileExtension: true)
  let jpgFiles:[String]? = FileManager.default.getSortedFilesAtDocumentDirectoryWith(fileExtension: "jpg", withFileExtension: true)
  let files = [textFiles, jpgFiles]

  let filesTVC = segue.destination as? FilesTableViewController
  filesTVC!.files = files
```

> ERROR on the last line: Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are different types. One is of type `[[String]?]` and the other is of type `[[String]]?`. Modify the declaration of `files` to `[[String]?]` to fix your issue:

```
var files: [[String]?]
```

Comment: I will accept the answer as soon as SO let me... in 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively get rid of **all** optionals (non-optionals will never crash), declare `files` as non-optional empty array

```
var files = [[String]]()
```

and assign an empty array if the result of `getSortedFilesAt...` is `nil`

```
let textFiles = FileManager.default.getSortedFilesAtDocumentDirectoryWith(fileExtension: "txt", withFileExtension: true) ?? []
let jpgFiles = FileManager.default.getSortedFilesAtDocumentDirectoryWith(fileExtension: "jpg", withFileExtension: true) ?? []
let files = [textFiles, jpgFiles]

let filesTVC = segue.destination as! FilesTableViewController
filesTVC.files = files
```